# Error "| was unexpected at this time."

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, findstr, netstat, taskkill

I am using code as below to delete program using port 8080, but I got error `| was unexpected at this time.`, what can I do?

```
FOR /F "tokens=5 delims= " %P IN ('netstat -a -n -o | findstr :8080') DO TaskKill.exe /PID %P
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The condition inside the `for` must be parsed by the batch parser before it can pass it to the IN() clause as an executable command. To preserve special characters like <, >, &, |, ^, or %, you have to escape them in the script. The escape character in Batch is "^".

Escape the vertical bar with a caret:

```
FOR /F "tokens=5 delims= " %P IN ('netstat -a -n -o ^| findstr :8080') DO TaskKill.exe /PID %P
```

I might also add that when saved as a .bat, the percent characters have to be escaped as well. Instead of "%P", you would need to use "%%P".

Comment: This would be a much better answer if you were to [edit] and explain *why* the poster should do so. It would be an educational answer that would benefit not only the asker of this question, but others who see it in the future. *Do this* doesn't provide any information about why it is necessary to do so.

Comment: Much better answer. :-)